# Wordpress : Remove JavaScript code from search result page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I’m using a slideshow on a wordpress site (Layerslider).

It creates some javascript code inside the source code (like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lsjQuery = jQuery;</script><script type="text/javascript">
    lsjQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // code from the slider
    }
});
</script>
```

The issue is that when i search something on the website with the native search field, the javaScript is visible in the result. I've tried with a native theme (Twenty Fourteen) and the issue is still here.

See screenshot :

[image]

Do you know how to remove this code from the result ?

Comment: what's your wordpress site url ?

Comment: @Cattla the result page : http://www.famdt.com/?s=COMMISSION+SPECTACLE+VIVANT

Comment: where do you write your script, at your page it appears in a paragraph, with no `<script>` around it?

Comment: @NatureShade It's the slider which integrates the script in the source code, like here http://www.famdt.com/commission-spectacle-vivant/ (search that in the source code : var lsjQuery = jQuery;)

Comment: The question is how to filter the search result and exclude javascript code

Comment: because in this post http://www.famdt.com/commission-spectacle-vivant/ there is a slideshow. remove the slideshow or write something excerpt for this post http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt